# python pandas normalization

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, database-normalization

I have a csv file where one field should be normalized over two records:

```
    +-----+---------+
    | id  | field   |
    +-----+---------+
    | 1   | A-a,B-b |
    | 2   | C-c     |
    +-----+---------+
```

so some records are comma separated with two tuples
to become different records

```
    +-----+---------+
    | id  | field   |
    +-----+---------+
    | 1   | A-a     |
    | 1   | B-b     |
    | 2   | C-c     |
    +-----+---------+
```

and then split over two fields

```
    +-----+---------+---------+
    | id  | field_1 | field_2 |
    +-----+---------+---------+
    | 1   | A       | a       |
    | 1   | B       | b       |
    | 2   | C       | c       |
    +-----+---------+---------+
```

I have this solution for the last step

```
df[['field_1', 'field_2']] = df['field'].str.split('-', expand = True)
```

but I'm missing the first step. Can you help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df.field = df.field.str.split(',')
df1 = df.explode('field')
df1[['field_1', 'field_2']] = df1.field.str.split('-', expand = True)
df1
 
   id field field_1 field_2
0   1   A-a       A       a
0   1   B-b       B       b
1   2   C-c       C       c
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with a single regex and `str.extractall`:

```
out = df.join(df['field']
              .str.extractall(r'(?P<field_1>[^-,]+)-(?P<field_2>[^-,]+)')
              .droplevel(1)
             )
```

output:

```
   id    field field_1 field_2
0   1  A-a,B-b       A       a
0   1  A-a,B-b       B       b
1   2      C-c       C       c
```